# How to push configuration from one module to another module in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, configuration

I'm looking for a way to "send" or "register" some configuration from several modules to one single module.

The idea is that different modules will have theirs own route configuration. And one single module controller will build the menu based on those configurations.

I want to "send" or "register" configuration instead of querying, because the menu controller cannot knows which modules are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to my need:

Each module defines its own routes using $routeProvider with a custom parameter defining if the route should be displayed in the menu and another custom parameter with the name to display. (See above Module A example).

Then the menu controller will loop the $route.routes variable (which contains all defined routes) to build de menu. (See above Module B example).

Module A:

```
angular
  .module('module-a', ['ngRoute'])

  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/path-a', {
        controller: 'ModuleAController',
        templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html',
        menuDisplay: true, // Custom parameter
        displayName: 'Solution Manager' // Custom parameter
      });
  });
```

Module B:

```
angular
  .module('module-b', [])

  .controller('MenuController', ['$scope', '$route',  function ($scope, $route) {
    var entries = [];
    angular.forEach($route.routes, function (route, path) {
      if ( route.menuDisplay == true ) {
        this.push({
          displayName: route.displayName,
          route: '#' + path
        });
      }
    }, entries);
    $scope.menu = entries;
  }]);
```

You will probably add some more checks to ensure displayName is provided, etc ...